# Fix the coordinates ordering of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to make a DataFrame to store several datasets taken from measurement tests.
The data has 8 dimensions (dims) to specify the test condition.
{*'Machine','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos(ition)'*}.

When I made a DataFrame from the tests, I found that the dimensions were made into alphabetical order, i.e.:
{*'Axis', 'Compensation', 'Machine', 'Month', 'Pos','SensorID','Year'*}.

So the output looks like following figure.
[image: dimensions forced into alphabetical order]

For the ease of understanding of the data, I would like to preserve the initial ordering of the dimensions
{*'Machine','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'*}.

Is there a way to preserve the initial ordering of the dimensions?
Or is there a better way to handle this kind of high-dimensional data?

The Python code is shown below.
For example, I got 3 data taken from different Machines, namely 'MC_A', 'MC_B', and 'MC_C'.
The data were stored in DataArray 'da', 'da2', and 'da3', respectivley.
To create a DataFrame to store them, I used 'merge' method.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

x = np.linspace(0,1500,16)
y = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y2 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y3 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))

da = xr.DataArray(y, dims=('Machine','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                    coords={'Machine':['MC_A'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                    name='val')

da2 = xr.DataArray(y2, dims=('Machine','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                    coords={'Machine':['MC_B'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                    name='val')

da3 = xr.DataArray(y3, dims=('Machine','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                    coords={'Machine':['MC_C'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                    name='val')

ds = xr.merge([da,da2,da3])
# print(da)
df = ds.to_dataframe()
# df.reorder_levels(['Machine','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','Errors','Pos'])

df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Do you actually need to use XArray? In the example you gave, you can directly instanciate DataFrames and then concatenate them.

```py
da = pd.DataFrame({'Machine':['MC_A'],'Year':['2020'],
                   'Month': 'Aug'],'Compensation':[1], 
                   'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x})
...
ds = pd.concat([da, da1, da2])
```

2 - If you do, you can merge the dataframes instead of the

```py
df = pd.concat([da.to_dataframe(), da2.to_dataframe(), da3.to_dataframe()])
```

Note that pandas < 1.0 used to sort the columns by default, so you had to pass `sort=False` to `concat`.